# Retrofit OutOfMemory exception while loading a files in BASE64 to server

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I had an OOM exception when tried to load a pdf file in base64 as a field in a model throw Retrofit. I know, than this is not a normal way to upload files, but it's not a third party realisation. How I can fix this kind of a problem?

An application crached when I switching off my network connection

```
Failed to allocate a 30544558 byte allocation with 2085152 free bytes and 26MB until OOM

@Streaming
@POST("/api/order/")
fun makeOrder(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body order: OrderMainModel): Single<Response<PhoneNumberResponse>>
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty crazy way of sending files. But despite it being wrong (as you normally do those things with `@Multipart`), I found your problem an interesting exercise. My solution is full of hacks, but if you're absolutely sure you can't influence the API in any way, then maybe this can help you.

You'll need an `InputStream`. There's no other way you'll be able to send files without eventually running out of memory. But how to send an `InputStream` in a request like this?

I assume `OrderMainModel` has a `String` field that keeps your giant Base64 string. I'd start by changing this to the `File` (or an `InputStream` itself).

Now, assuming you're using Gson (that's a pretty bold assumption but that's a parser I use - I'm pretty sure you can achieve something similar with any reasonable json library), create a custom `TypeAdapter` for type `File`. This `TypeAdapter` will force you to implement this interface:

```
class Adapter : TypeAdapter<File>() {
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: File) {
        // implement this

    }

    override fun read(`in`: JsonReader): File {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

You can leave `read` alone, you won't need it.

Now, what you have to do in the `write` method is to read it part by part, continuously writing it to `JsonWriter`. Ah, and whatever you read, you'll need to convert it to base64 on the fly. There's a `Base64InputStream` available in `android.util` but it doesn't seem to be capable of encoding, you can use this one, from `commons-codec`: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html (remember to pass `true` to `doEncode` in a constructor, otherwise it'll work in decoding mode).

Now, everything you have to do is to make `Base64InputStream` wrap `FileInputStream`, which wraps `File` you received in your `TypeAdapter`.

```
// 0 means no new lines in your Base64. null means no line separator. 
Base64InputStream(FileInputStream(file)), true, 0, null)
```

And slowly re-write it back to your `JsonWriter`.

But wait, that's not easy either!

`JsonWriter` doesn't offer any reasonable way of writing a single string (value) in a streaming fashion. The only idea I have is to hack it with reflection.

In order to do that, you need to retrieve `JsonWriter`'s inner `out` object, type of `Writer`. Then, in order to be able to write to do it without breaking the state that `JsonWriter` keeps internally, you need to get an access on `Writer`'s two private methods - `writeDeferredValue` and `beforeValue` and invoke them in order. Everything gets quite complicated and unsafe. But hey, it's all about fun, isn't it?

Here's a small PoC that presents the idea, rather not prod ready. ;-)

```
fun main() {
    val model = Model(File("file.txt"))
    val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(File::class.java, Adapter()).create()
    // System.out just for PoC, don't try with large files because output will be massive
    gson.toJson(model, System.out)
}

data class Model(@SerializedName("file") val file: File)

class Adapter : TypeAdapter<File>() {
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: File) {
        Base64InputStream(FileInputStream(value), true, 0, null).use { 
            out.writeFromStream(it)
        }
    }

    override fun read(`in`: JsonReader): File {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    // JsonWriter only offers value(String), which would need you to load the whole file to the memory.
    private fun JsonWriter.writeFromStream(inputStream: InputStream) {
        val declaredField = javaClass.getDeclaredField("out")
        val deferredName = javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("writeDeferredName")
        val beforeValue = javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("beforeValue")

        declaredField.isAccessible = true
        deferredName.isAccessible = true
        beforeValue.isAccessible = true

        val actualWriter = declaredField.get(this) as Writer

        deferredName.invoke(this)
        beforeValue.invoke(this)
        actualWriter.write("\"")
        for (byte in inputStream.buffered()) {
            actualWriter.write(byte.toInt())
        }
        actualWriter.write("\"")
    }
}
```

You can probably achieve a similar behaviour by integrating some lower-level HTTP APIs, which will let you write to the OutputStream without reflection. Perhaps some other parsers (Jackson, maybe?) would make it slightly more convenient.

... or just fight for the API change.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks about your answer, but I can't adapt your solution for my needs. I figured out that my app is crashing while tries to parse base64 to string, But inside my OrderMainModel I have an aditional info and I must send a lot of pds, not just this one. So I still trying to figure out a way around

Comment: Sure, no worries. If you would like to, try sharing the exact structure of your model + usecases that a potential solution needs to cater for. Perhaps the above can be adapted to support these - I can take a look when I have a sec (or maybe somebody else will help). Have a great weekend!

Comment: I recreated an answer, so you can take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035503/retrofit-with-rx-runs-outofmemory-while-trying-to-send-a-large-base64

Comment: And I partly tried to implement your solution (but instead of file I user inputStream), but I catch bad base64 error

Comment: I tested it and it worked - can you double check which Base64InputStream you are using? I used the one coming from commons-codec artifact - if you would use the one from android.util instead it will indeed result in a crash. If you are using commons-codec already, make sure you construct it properly - it has to work in encoding mode.

Comment: Well, I added commons-codes "'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'", but I've go a crash on 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(I[B)V in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

Comment: Oh, that's weird. Out of curiosity - does the same thing happen when you bump codec to 1.13? That's the version I used.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Maybe you have some other manifest or gradle code?

Comment: Well, It worked. I used Base64.encode(value, Base64.NO_WRAP), where value is byteArray. But it's crashing when I'm trying to handle a bunch of pdf (in my case 6 pdf, 20mb each). But thanks for your responses, I wish that this answers will help somebody