# Retrofit with RX runs OutOfMemory while trying to send a large BASE64

Tags: android, base64, retrofit2, rx-android

I want to send a model throw Retrofit, which contains some standard fields and files, encoded in BASE64 format. I know, that this is a crazy way to send files, but I have a server with no backend developer.

So, when I'm sending, for example, 3 pdf files 20mb each, I runs out of memory which exception like this

> Failed to allocate a 30544558 byte allocation with 2085152 free bytes and 26MB until OOM

I figured out, that it's a problem in parse of base64 string, which I'm already have in memory to Json throw GSON. I tried to create to create a custom adapter, according to [Retrofit OutOfMemory exception while loading a files in BASE64 to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981532/retrofit-outofmemory-exception-while-loading-a-files-in-base64-to-server) but runs out of ideas in case of a large model. What will fix this problem with passing of a large string to a JSON? Maybe I can use other adapters, not a GSON?

Model of documents field in Json and whole model

```
data class Document(
    var base64: MutableList<String?>,
    var mime: String?,
    var name: String?
)

data class OrderMainModel(
    var INN: String?,
    var KPP: String?,
    var addressOfEstateObject: String?,
    var addressOfGardenObject: String?,
    var agentFathersName: String?,
    var agentFirstName: String?,
    var agentLastName: String?,
    var approximateSizeOfEstateObject: Double?,
    var approximateSizeOfOKS: Double?,
    var area: String?,
    var bankAccountNumber: Int?,
    var companyAddress: String?,
    var companyName: String?,
    var documents: List<Document?>
}
```

Retrofit method

```
@Streaming
@POST("/api/order/")
fun makeOrder(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body order: OrderMainModel): Single<Response<PhoneNumberResponse>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should use Flowable with proper backpressure strategy instead of Single.
But if you think it's for your adapter you can use Jackson because it's faster than Gson(According to [this](https://medium.com/@dannydamsky99/heres-why-you-probably-shouldn-t-be-using-the-gson-library-in-2018-4bed5698b78b) article).
And if you want more performance maybe you should use Protobuf instead of JSON.